# Local decomposition of semisimple Lie groups at the identity into the product of centralizer, unstable and stable horospherical subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

First let us look at an example. Let $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $A$ be its subgroup consisting of diagonal matrices with positive entries.

Let $a\in A$ be an element. We define the *stable horospherical subgroup* of G corresponding
to $a$ to be $$U^−(a) = \{g \in G : a^{-n} g a^{n} \to e, \text{ as}~n\to -\infty \},$$

and we define the *unstable horospherical subgroup* of G corresponding
to $a$ to be $$U^+(a) = \{g \in G : a^{-n} g a^{n} \to e, \text{ as}~n\to +\infty \}.$$

There is a classical result saying that there is a local diffeomorphism at the identity element from $G$ to the product $Z(a)U^+(a)U^-(a)$, where $Z(a)$ consists of elements that commute with $a$. This decomposition can be shown through the computation of derivative of the product map at the identity as well as adding the dimensions and then use the inverse function theorem.(Please let me know if the above statements are correct.)

My question is, does this result generalize naturally to any semisimple Lie group $G$ and $a$ in some subgroup $A$ of $G$ (say maximal torus)? What would be the precise statement of this theorem and how to give/where to find its proof? Because of its dynamical nature, I can't find such result (even the above example) in any regular Lie group books. I only learnt such through papers, for example this one:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.4289.pdf#page=4#

Comment: It generalises to split real groups but not to e.g. compact ones. Let $A$ be the connected component of a maximal torus, containing $e$. The centraliser of any $a\in A$ is a Levi subgroup and the subgroup $Z(a)U^+(a)$ is a parabolic subgroup. (To see this: the set of roots $\alpha$ with $\alpha(a) >0$ can be included in a positive system.) The local diffeomorphism at the identity follows immediately from the decomposition of the roots into the three subsets with $\alpha(a) >0$, $=0$, $<0$.